# How to provide your own delimiter for cin?

Tags: c++, user-input, codeblocks, ubuntu-11.04

In c, I can use newline delimeter ([^\n]) with scanf. Using which I can store the line. Similarly for cin, I can use getline.

If I have to store a paragraph, I can simulate the functionality using my own special char delimiter like [^#] or [^\t] with scanf function in c.

```
char a[30];
scanf("%[^\#]",a);
printf("%s",a);
```

How to achieve the similar functionality with cin object in cpp.

Comment: getline takes an optional third argument for a delimiter (which defaults to `'\n'`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[istream.getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) lets you specify a deliminator to use instead of the default `'\n'`:

```
cin.getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

or the safer and easier way is to use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).  With this method you don't have to worry about allocating a buffer large enough to fit your text.

```
string s;
getline(cin, s, '\t');
```

EDIT:

Just as a side note since it sounds like you are just learning c++ the proper way to read multiple deliminated lines is:

```
string s;
while(getline(cin, s, '\t')){
    // Do something with the line
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GWW for your help. I was not aware of this. :-) I tested this and it helped.

Comment: Yes indeed I am learning c++. Thanks for the side note. I will keep that in mind.