# C++ How to use cin to store in more than 1 variable

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, user-input, cin

My question is for example I have 3 variables;

```
int y, m ,d;
```

Is there anyway that I can take user input in the form of YYYY/MM/DD and store YYYY into y, MM into m, and DD into d by using std::istream functions?

Comment: `char dummy; std::cin >> y >> dummy >>  m  >> dummy >>  d;`??

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c and possibly even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297623/how-to-provide-your-own-delimeter-for-cin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing the delimiter for cin (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't specify a delimiter with >> you can use the following:

```
std::string input;
cin.getline(input, 4, '/');
```

Then you would convert that to int by doing:
    int years = std::stoi(input);